# Blocked - Blazor webassembly .DLL files failed to download

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, progressive-web-apps, blazor-webassembly

TL DR: Can't get around the .dll ban.

In order to resolve the problem in topic, we have tried the following methods:

Method #1: Change file extension.
Some discussions such as [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5477) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-6.0#change-the-filename-extension-of-dll-files) offered to change the file extension from **.dll** to **.bin**. But as of today my antivirus software will also block .bin files. I don't think trying a different file extension would help. Because even if it fools the antivirus today, when tomorrow an upgraded antivirus would not be fooled by file extension, it is not going to be pleasant.

Method #2: Build the client with AOT enabled. However the deployment package still contains .dll files and they are blocked just like in #1.

Method #3:
Another solution is mentioned [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/custom-deployment-layout-for-blazor-webassembly-apps/). I have not tried out, because its [nuget package page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.MultipartBundle#readme-body-tab) mentioned it does not support production use. The risk is unknown and probably the management will not approve.

Is there a solution for using Blazor? If not, it seems the only way is to use a Javascript framework such as Angular or Vue for the development of a PWA.

Below is a screenshot of some of the console errors:
[image]

Comment: Did you check the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/progressive-web-app?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)?

Answer (score 2):

My work runs Sophos, which appears to allow DLLs to be served if you're serving them from a site using SSL - perhaps whatever AV you're running will also allow that?

Here's my complete launchSettings.json for reference, the only modifications I made to my project were in setting the sslPort and modifying the profile's applicationUrl:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "sslPort": 44365 //port between 44300-44399 required, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-without-administrative-privileges#using-ssl
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "Demo.Website": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44365"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually this problem es into process due to a change into files.

Something has changed the contents of the files between the build and delivery of the files to the browser.
You can try "this simple steps":

1. Closing VS,
2. Cleaning (removing) the bin and obj folders
3. and recompile/rebuild

But, if the problem persists you can try running this PS [integrity.ps1 > Troubleshoot integrity PowerShell script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-6.0#troubleshoot-integrity-powershell-script)
 that validates, publishes and deploys a blazor app. And then you can detect the problem depending on whether this tools/script works.